# Python selenium web scrape dynamic content within a nested span that has no class name

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to parse out a dynamic content in a nested span structure. The text I want to get is "dynamic content2" which is the content of the second span element (class = "second span") and its value is being updated regularly.

```
<html>
<div class="outer div">
     <span class="first span">
           <span>random content</span>
     </span>
     <span class="second span">
           <span>dynamic content2</span>
     </span>
</div>
</html>
```

I am new to web scraping, and currently this is what I have:

```
import os, sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


opts = Options()
opts.add_argument(" --headless")

chrome_driver = os.getcwd() +"\\chromedriver.exe"

# Instantiate a webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts, executable_path=chrome_driver)
driver.get("some url")

soup_file=driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(soup_file)

# works fine
print(soup.title.get_text())

print("Testing getting dynamic element")

spanId = 'second span'
mySpan = soup.find("span", class_ = spanId )
print(mySpan.get_text())
driver.quit()
```

But there is nothing returned. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the output as `dynamic content2`

Code:

```
tag="""
<html>
<div class="outer div">
     <span class="first span">
           <span>random content</span>
     </span>
     <span class="second span">
           <span>dynamic content2</span>
     </span>
</div>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(tag, 'html.parser')

#span= soup.select_one('div.outer.div > span.second.span >span').text
#or
span= soup.select_one('span.second.span >span').text
print(span)
```

Output:

```
dynamic content2
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, if the class name for second span involves some special character like 

<span class="border-color-main-secondary px-3.5 py-1 md:py-1.5 ">
           <span>dynamic content2</span>
 </span>

Should I put \ to escape those characters ? Still not getting the dynamic content with error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: Actually, according to your html doc my solution is correct . From your comment I can see that span tag contains multiple classes. Each space separates the class value. Your's comment correct selection is as follows: 
        span.border-color-main-secondary.px-3.5.py-1.md:py-1.5